# imagettftext not displaying the image

Tags: php, image, gd, imagettftext

I'm using the following code in the `test.php` file to generate an image from a text.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = '/home/axxxxxxx/public_html/font.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Then I'm trying to display the image in the `test2.php` as follows

```
<?php
echo "<img src=\"/test.php\" />";
?>
```

All I get is the default broken image icon. The path to the font file and image url is correct. All file permission are at 777. The servers do have the GD library.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when accessing test.php directly? I'm guessing an error message.

Comment: @Maerlyn I get the same result as the test2.php, *default broken image icon*

Comment: Comment out the `header` call so you see the error message.

Comment: Now I get a set of characters starting from `�PNG  IHDR��߇ �IDATx���[`... (which means the images gets created.) But I get the same result as the test2.php, *default broken image icon*

Comment: @sid You probably have a BOM at the start of file test2.php. Please see the relevant section of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php/8028987#8028987

Comment: Be sure to check also at the end of the data - an errormessage could have been appended to your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. As Danak suggested, I saved the file as `UTF-8 Without BOM` using the notepad++. Then Is simply started displaying the image correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the missing font. Please copy the font file in the test.php directory and change code:

```
$font = '/home/axxxxxxx/public_html/font.ttf';
```

to

```
$font = 'font.ttf';
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a wrong offset. The image was showing nothing, no text, no errors in the source code, just a blank file. The paths were correct. I thought there was an error in the ttf font but turns out it was just wrong positioning.

Here's what helped me to see a bit of the text:

```
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 20, 20, $fg, $font, $text);
```

This shows a bit of text on the top right.

Full working code:

```
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . dirname(__FILE__));
    $font = 'arial'; // located next to the script
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 20, 20, $fg, $font, $text);
```